# JavaMelody strange information

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, monitoring, java-melody

I'm new to JavaMelody. "Statistics http - 1 day" block displays following info:
[image]
 [(link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDlMD.png)

As you can see I have a lot of `select` requests and max time is 128ms. Ok, I'm moving down and checking "Current requests" block:
[image]
[(link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTwaA.png)

I have 3 requests at this moment that require much more time to execute than 128ms!
Why JavaMelody displays wrong info in "Statistics http" block and "Http mean times" graph? Have I misunderstood displayed info?

Comment: I can't read the columns in the second image.

Comment: check this link - http://i.stack.imgur.com/oTwaA.png

Comment: Current requests are not finished yet.They should be put into stats once they are finished. Check also if you are looking at correct timeframe.

Comment: Piotr, yes they are not finished. But they are the same as previous. I know that previous requests was executing about same time